# Loop through dynamic sql query using different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor

I'm currently working on an sql task and I need help on the query. So basically, I'm trying to loop through several tables, with similar columns (though with different data in it).

I did so by passing through a string of the table names with commas as the delimiter. Then I split the string using the function `[dbo].[ufn_tbSplit]` which then return a temp table with a column called 'Token' that stored the tables' names.

So, here, I use cursor to loop through each table. No problem there. But the problem come when I want to loop the `+ ' UNION SELECT DISTINCT [Die_X_Position], [Die_Y_Position] FROM '` statement. If I only have 2 tables, then it will be no problem. But what if I have around 5 tables? I want to loop the union statement so that it will include all the other tables as well. How can I achieve this? I'm currently using MS SQL Server 2008 R2. Thanks!

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Token FROM [dbo].[ufn_tbSplit](@TableString_IN, ',')
OPEN C1
FETCH next FROM C1 INTO @TempTable
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
    SET @xDie1 = @TempTable 
    FETCH next FROM C1 INTO @TempTable 
    SET @xDie2 = @TempTable
    SET @xDie = 'SELECT DISTINCT [Die_X_Position], [Die_Y_Position] FROM ' + @xDie1
                + ' UNION SELECT DISTINCT [Die_X_Position], [Die_Y_Position] FROM ' + @xDie2 
    EXEC sp_executesql @xDie
    FETCH next FROM C1 INTO @TempTable
END
CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have what you need.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = ''
DECLARE @sqlTemplate varchar(max)
set @sqlTemplate = ' SELECT DISTINCT [Die_X_Position], [Die_Y_Position] FROM '
DECLARE @i int
set @i = 0
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Token FROM [dbo].[ufn_tbSplit](@TableString_IN, ',')
OPEN C1
FETCH next FROM C1 INTO @TempTable
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
    if @i <> 0
    begin
      set @sql = @sql + ' UNION ' + @sqlTemplate + @TempTable
    end
    else
    begin
      set @sql = @sqlTemplate + @TempTable
    end
    set @i = @i + 1
    FETCH next FROM C1 INTO @TempTable
END
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

Comment: You can add a print statement instead of the exec statement to display your @sql variable to make sure that its what you need.

Comment: Yeah, that solved my problem! Thanks a lot! :D Do you mind if I ask another question though?

Comment: @shfly3424, not at all, ask away

Comment: suppose the column names are slightly different, say, just using `[Die X]` instead of `[Die_X_Position]`, or something along the line, is there any alternate way to standardized them to put into the sql query, other than renaming the column name?

Comment: @shfly3424 Not sure if I understand exactly, but an alias might be what you are looking for.  if you do something like `select [Die_X_Position] as [Die X]` (if you have a space you need the square brackets, otherwise you can omit those, the `as` can also be omitted, but helps with readability)  That will display the column as `Die X`.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @shfly3424, oh.  I think I understand.  You are suggesting that the column names change between tables subtly.  For that, the sql string needs to know what columns its going to choose.  What if you stored the tablename and column names in a table in the database, then just generated the sql that way?  That seems much easier to maintain than sending in a comma delimited string.

Comment: yes yes, exactly what you said on your second comment. Some of the tables might have a slight different column names, but still with the same meaning/values. Are you suggesting to store the list of tables and column names in a table/temp table?
Right now, I'm doing a stored procedure. It will have the list of tables as the parameter. But, I might have different number of tables each time I run the stored procedure. Hence, the best way I can think of is by passing the comma delimited string.

Comment: What are the criteria for the number of tables passed in to the stored procedure? Could those settings be put in a table?  do you call this sproc from an app or manually?

Comment: For this one, I get the tables from an .mdb file, create temp tables (for each table I retrieved) in the database and then use bulkcopy to insert the values to each particular table. All these are done in C#. Then, the C# will also call the stored procedure to transfer the data from these temp tables into its appropriate table (for example, all die values from these temp tables will be copied to the Die table). So, I would say there's no definite number of tables going to be passed. It's totally depends on the task on hand. So I'd have to make my C# and stored procedure as dynamic as possible.

Comment: I believe you need to re think your schema. You lose all the functionality of indexes and relational data in a model like that.